# Removing a TableCellElement from an Array stops innerHTML from working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, greasemonkey, alert

Using JavaScript in Greasemonkey, I'm attempting to pull individual cells and read the `innerHTML` of each cell to search for a given string.

There's a table of 3x3, and I want to search them in the order of the center first, then depending on situation, move to not-necessarily linear progression (i.e. top-left, top, left, top-right, bottom-left, right, bottom, bottom-right).

I've put each of the cells into an array, and using `splice()`, I assign the cell to a variable. For testing purposes, I throw up 2 alerts with the cell variable itself, then the cell `innerHTML`.

When I just use the variable, the alert says `[object HTMLTableCellElement]`, but the `innerHTML` is undefined.

I've created a mock page to show my example. here's the code ([Also at jsBin)](http://jsbin.com/ilezax/2).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4<br>
        center
    </td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script language="JavaScript">
    var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    tables[0].style.border = "thin solid red";
    tables[0].id = "grid";
    var grid = tables[0];
    var cells = new Array();
    cells[0] = grid.rows[0].cells[0]; // nw
    cells[1] = grid.rows[0].cells[1]; // n
    cells[2] = grid.rows[0].cells[2]; // ne
    cells[3] = grid.rows[1].cells[0]; // w
    cells[4] = grid.rows[1].cells[1]; // c
    cells[5] = grid.rows[1].cells[2]; // e
    cells[6] = grid.rows[2].cells[0]; // sw
    cells[7] = grid.rows[2].cells[1]; // s
    cells[8] = grid.rows[2].cells[2]; // se
    var grid_string = "";

    function HumanCount(cell) {
        var human_regex = /Human/;
        var humans = cell.innerHTML.split(human_regex);
        var humans_length = humans.length - 1;
        return humans_length;
    }
    for (a = 0; a < 9; a++) {
        cells[a].count = HumanCount(cells[a]);
        grid_string += cells[a].count + " ";
        if (a == 2 || a == 5) {
            grid_string += "<br>";
        }
    }
    var direction = 0; // nw
    var center = cells.splice(4, 1);

    alert("center: " + center);
    alert("innerHTML: " + center.innerHTML);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`center` is not an element, so it has no `innerHTML` property.
`center` is an *array of elements*, so if you use:

```
alert ("innerHTML: " + center[0].innerHTML);
```

you'll see what you expect.

~~~

That alert `alert("center: "+center);` is misleading, as it shows `<td>` the same as `[<td>]`.

For more accurate (and less annoying) debugging don't use `alert()`.  Use `console.log`, EG: `console.log ("center: ", center);` -- which would show the array as different from the element and doesn't throw up a modal dialog.

Comment: I didn't even think to treat it as an array when I pulled it out with splice. Thanks so much.